# How can i add a variable in AJAX URL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a function in php that need an id and i need to add a variable in my ajax url the id

PHP Code:

```
function get_json_selected($purpose) 
    {
        //echo $this->input->post("ids");
        $ids = explode(",", $this->input->post("ids"));
        $site_url = site_url($this->router->class);
        if ($purpose == "EQUIPEMENT"){
            $this->db->select(
                               'a.id,
                                a.manufacturer,
                                a.description,
                                a.serial_no,
                                a.part_no,
                                a.status, 
                                a.availability,
                                getReturnStatus(a.id) as return_status',
                                FALSE
                            );

            $this->db->where_in('a.id', array_unique($ids));

            $result = $this->db->get("equipments a")->result_array();
            echo json_encode(array("spares" => $result));
        } else {
            $this->db->select(
                               'a.id,
                                a.manufacturer,
                                a.description,
                                a.serial_no,
                                a.part_no,
                                a.status, 
                                a.availability,
                                getReturnStatus(a.id) as return_status',
                                FALSE
                            );

            $this->db->where_in('a.id', array_unique($ids));

            $result = $this->db->get($this->active_table." a")->result_array();
            echo json_encode(array("spares" => $result));
        }


    }
```

Ajax Code:

this is just example of the variable of id.

```
$purpose = "EQUIPMENT"; // how can i add this php variable to ajax url

url: "<?=site_url('equip_request/get_json_selected');?>", // this is the current code how can i add id in this url
```

or is this code right?

```
url: "<?=site_url('equip_request/get_json_selected/'.$purpose);?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var purpose = '<?php echo json_encode($purpose); ?>';

url: 'example.php?=' + purpose;
```

`+` is the concatenator in javascript. hope this helps. spend plenty of time and add plenty of security to echoing that var into javascript. else you could find yourself viction of xss.

Comment: slightly i cant understand what do you mean because im sorry to say im just newbie in ajax xD